# Angular 2 quick start tutorial issues (nested components)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

Hey everyone i'm learning Angular 2 following the quick start tutorial but i'm using a template I downloaded from thenewboston, because its configured to convert typescript to java script, in short my issue is when I try to nest the herodetailcomponent it wont even show on click of the list, nor will it result in any errors in chrome's console. Here are my files I know there are alot but Im not sure if im making an easily recognized mistake.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.21",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "typings": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types" : []
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "app/js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

main.ts:

```
    /*import {bootstrap}    from 'angular/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
 */
 import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular2/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

hero.ts

```
    export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

hero-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="hero">
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
`

})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  @Input()
  hero:Hero;

}
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
//import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';



const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' }, 
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
//this is two way
template:`
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
<li *ngFor= "let hero of heroes"   [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
  <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
</li>

</ul>
 <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>

`,
  styles: [`
    ignore this
  `]

}) 

export class AppComponent {
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
heroes=HEROES;
selectedHero: Hero;

onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}

}
```

Comment: Typescript is always compiled as JavaScript on runtime not matter what template you use... just as a comment.

Comment: Can you link the template?

Comment: Oh, that makes a difference, i was confused because in the newboston tutorial the file hierarchy the app folder contains a ts and a js folder, (the js files were generated).

Comment: This is the template, Ihowever updated everything in the  package.json file and npm installed it again.

Comment: https://github.com/buckyroberts/angular-2-template

Comment: @GBravo That is an OOOOOOLD template, why would you use that? :D I suggest you use one that is up to date...https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html for example :)

Comment: @GBravo That is also probably why your template doesn't work, since it's so old and not compatible with your code/settings.

Comment: yeah, i just caved and used the new one works great, thanks everyone